# Is there a way in Windows to set up an automatic "suspend" on downloads when another program is being used?

Tags: windows-xp, automation

Sorry for the confused question.

This is the situation:

I use utorrent occasionally.
I also use a VOIP phone.

If I am using utorrent, it eats up so much bandwidth that my phone (poor quality at best) completely becomes unusable.

To combat this, I try to remember to pause utorrent when I use the phone, but sometimes I am so bust that I forget.

Is there a way to automate utorrent so that as soon as I am using my voip phone (VBuzzer), utorrent will pause?

Thanks,
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, although you can right click on the Utorrent icon and change the bandwidth usage.

Personally, you may want to upgrade your router to one that (or find out if it) supports [QoS (Quality of Service)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_Service), this will allow you to write rules that can automatically reduce torrent bandwidth when VoIP traffic is detected.

Windows also has a QoS driver you can install as an optional component, but I have no experience with this and cannot advise further on it, but may be worth doing a bit of research.